# Storing and later calling member function of unknown class

Tags: c++, boost-thread, pointer-to-member

I am trying to create a threadpool that can run functions from unknown classes. I do not wish to have to create non-members as a proxy.
I have managed to create a working pool & workerthread class and a task structure, all of these are templates.

```
// ThreadPool.h
/* Threadpool creates N WorkerThreads (each worker has a ptr to the creating pool), 
    these block until a task is ready then call ThreadPool::doTask() */
template<class T>
struct Task {
    Task() : func(0), inst(0) { }

    Task(boost::function<void(T*)> function, T* instance) : func(0), inst(0) {
        func = function;
        inst = instance;
    }

    void operator()() {
        Task::func(inst);
    }

    T* inst;
    boost::function<void(T*)> func;
};

template<class T>
class ThreadPool {
    template<class T> friend class WorkerThread;
public:

    void addTask(Task<T> task) {
        ... // Some stuff
    }

    bool doTask() {
        Task<T> task;

        ... // Gets a task from std::queue

        // Check the task actually exists!
        if(task.func && task.inst) {
            // Do the task
            (task)();
        }
    }
private:
    std::queue<Task<T>> mTasks;
};
```

As is, this code works, providing I determine the class for ThreadPool and Task. But I want to be able to call members of unknown class types. I had considered a void ptr but I could not find a way to convert this to a valid instance ptr. I have also looked into boost::mem_fun but struggled to really get to grips with it.

I have briefly read about C++0x and from what I understand, it should make solving my problem easier but I would like to solve this before then, if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a T* at all, instead of just `boost::function<void ()>`?

That way you can use free functions as well as member functions, and you can simplify your code.

A task for a member on an instance of class X could be queued like this:

```
poll.add(boost::bind(&X::member, x_instance, other_arguments));
```

With no casts and no templates in your code.

Update:

Use boost::function instead of your Task class. You then just need to keep track of the instances and call them as appropriate. For example:

```
class TaskQueue {
    std::deque<boost::function<void ()> > m_tasks;

public:
    void add(boost::function<void ()> const& f) { m_tasks.push_back(f); }
    bool has_task() const { return !m_tasks.empty(); }
    void do_task() {
        m_tasks.front()();
        m_tasks.pop_front();
    }
};

int example_enqueue(TaskQueue* tq) {
    boost::shared_ptr<RandomClass> rc(new RandomClass);
    tq->add(boost::bind(&RandomClass::method, rc, arg_1, arg_whatever));
}
```

Note that by combining this method with boost::shared_ptr, you get automatic destruction of your objects when the function goes out of scope, if it's the last reference. That makes life a lot easier.

Comment: This looks like it could be my solution, but how exactly do I store that as a variable for later use?

Answer (score 0):

A void* would work. You just have to do a strong `reinterpret_cast`. But I would not use this solution. Boost has a bunch of ways of creating functor objects: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function.html